# Using relative redirect in spring boot fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, nginx, redirect

## Scenario

I have an spring-boot application which is accessed using context instead domain root:

- domain root : http://app.com
- my app : http://app.com/organization_a (redirects me to **my app login**)
- my app login : http://app.com/organization_a/login (form is loaded perfectly)

## Problem

After success login, using the classic configuration:

```
formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/my_form")
```

redirects me to : http://app.com/my_form throwing an error because the url must be : http://app.com/organization_a/my_form

So,  I tried to use relative url (note the dot before /my_form)  **./my_form** instead **/my_form**

```
formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("./my_form")
```

And spring throw me this error : **defaultTarget must start with '/' or with 'http(s)** due to this validation in spring-security-web jar:

```
//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler
public void setDefaultTargetUrl(String defaultTargetUrl) {
    Assert.isTrue(UrlUtils.isValidRedirectUrl(defaultTargetUrl),
            "defaultTarget must start with '/' or with 'http(s)'");
    this.defaultTargetUrl = defaultTargetUrl;
}
```

> So, I can say: Classic default success url method does not allow to use relative urls, because if I use root domain , works like charm as in my localhost.

## Relative vs Absolute urls

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39545949/3957754)

I had similar troubles with html and assets in java an other languages like php and nodejs.

Basically if you are using context instead a domain root for your app, you must need to change this:

```
<link href="/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

to

```
<link href="./vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Note the dot before /vendor/bootstrap/...

Without this dot, your assets will not download because the browser request to  urls like :

- http://app.com/main.css
- http://app.com/app.js

When should it be:

- http://app.com/organization_a/main.css
- http://app.com/organization_a/app.js

## Current workarounds

- Use domain or subdomain instead context.

  - This is laborious because I will need to open a ticket to my ISP for every new app.
- Put the entire url in **defaultSuccessUrl** method.

  - This is awful because my app will not be portable due to I must set the absolute url **before build**:

```
    formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("http://app.com/organization_a/my_form")
```

## Question

> Is there a way to use relative redirect in spring security?

I am using one of the latest spring boot versions: **2.1.7.RELEASE**

Any help or comment are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You already checked out the code and according to the code this is not possible.

Comment: I trying with AuthenticationSuccessHandler. I feel that I am close.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to enable relative redirects via the following spring properties:

```
server:
  tomcat:
    use-relative-redirects: true
```